# Magnetic field on a super conductor cylinder

Tags: magnetic-fields, symmetry, superconductivity, maxwell-equations

Suppose that  i have a cylinder of the z axis.
I'll put this cylinder on a uniform magnetic field with magnitude of B0 along de y axis.

Since we have B = 0 inside the superconductor, this will generate a magnetic field with magnitude of -B0 along the y axis.

Now, how can i find the current generated by this field on the surface of the cylinder?

Comment: I cannot understand your question. Is the cylinder along the z-axis a superconductor ? Please improve your question to make it clearer.

Comment: The cylinder is along the z-axis.

Comment: The cylinder is along the z-axis.
The cylinder is a SC.
There`s an external magnetic field B = B0 along the y-axis.

What will happen when i put the cylinder inside this field?

I wan't to  determine B at all space.
Also, i want to know the superficial current along the cylinder.